# What should I specify in an invitation letter for parents and siblings visiting UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, family

My wife's parents and siblings are planning to visit my family in the UK. We are all Indonesians by nationality. They need to apply for family visitor visas, and one of the documents I need to supply them is an invitation letter.

- What do I need to specify in this invitation letter?
- Do I need to write one letter for each visitor or can it be combined?
- Who should sign the letter? Is it I, my wife, or both of us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a site](http://www.sampleinvitationletter.info/index.php) that provides information and samples for various visa invitation letters for various countries.  There is a link on there specifically for [UK visa letters](http://sampleinvitationletter.info/sample_invitation_sponsorship_letter_visitor_visa.php).

If that is insufficient you can look at the samples provided by [University of Greenwich](http://www2.gre.ac.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0005/769388/Sample_invitation_letter_to_provide_in_support_of_visitor_visa_application1.pdf), [University of Sheffield](http://www.shef.ac.uk/union/advice/international/files/sampleletterofinvitation.doc), or [De Montfort University](http://www.dmu.ac.uk/documents/dmu-students/international-student-support/family-visit-letter-template.pdf).

As far as signature is concerned if you are on a Work Visa then it would be better to come from you.  If you're both permanent residents it probably won't make much of a differences.

Comment: Do you have any idea whether one letter would suffice for all visitors or should I write one letter for each visitor?

Comment: @adipro That would have to depend on their ages and whether or not they will be able to apply as a single application.  I am guessing 1 letter per application but even if you have to write X the only thing that's changing is the name.